# Trigger Firebase function onUpdate of document field value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I am looking for a solution to making the below code trigger `onUpdate` of a field value, rather than by the entire document.

Is it possible using the `firebase-functions` package to listen to a field value, let's say a field with a time stamp called `lastUpdate`? Alternatively, I am leaning toward a `HTTP` trigger called via `onClick` using `axios` but cannot find any resources, documentation or tutorials that help my understanding. If you know of any, I'd love to read them.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

try {
  admin.initializeApp();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

var SENDGRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key;
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

exports = module.exports = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{id}')
  .onUpdate(snap => {
    const user = snap.data();
    const msg = {
      to: user.email,
      from: 'example@example.com',
      templateId: 'd-6c0e0385808c480ab475748a6eeed773',
      dynamic_template_data: {
        firstName: user.firstName,
        email: user.email,
        id: user.id
      }
    };
    return sgMail.send(msg).catch(err => console.log(`${user.email} - ${err}`));
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloud Firestore triggers Cloud Functions on a document level. There is no option to trigger a function only when a specific field in the document is changed. If you want that level of granularity for your triggers, consider using the realtime database.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I had concluded much the same but thought I would ask in case there was some work around. To fix my issue I created a seperate `doc` for user alerts, then I brought my fields into this `doc` using `onUpdate` to trigger the `send(msg)`. Thank you again for clarifying.